# Text file to array in java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I want to read a text file

> 0 2 100 1
>
> 2 0 7 100
>
> 100 7 0 11
>
> 1 100 11 0

into `array[][]` in java. I am new to computer science and don't know much about java. I am trying to make changes to the following code (which was written by someone else) to do the task.

```
int rows = 4; int cols = 4;

FileInput in = new FileInput(args[0]);

int[][] val = new int[rows][cols]; 

String[] line;

for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) 
{
    line = in.readString().split("\t");
}

for(int j=0; j < cols; j++) 
{
    val[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
}
```

Comment: are you sure your text file contains tab-separated fields? If not, the split() command won't work

Comment: also what is your FileInput class? Do you have any import statements?

Comment: i am not sure what to say, sorry. i really dont know much about computer sciences. i just want to create 4x4 matrix array and the data is stored in txt file (in the above format) saved in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loops need to be nested like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) 
{
    line = in.readString().split("\t");
    for(int j=0; j < cols; j++) 
    {
        val[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
    }
}
```

Also check that your file is correctly formatted i.e. it has tabs to separate the numbers on each line.

Comment: thanks. can you please help me understand in.readString method? why string? should that not be in.readInteger()? the file above doesnt have strings. strings are like letters, arent they?

Comment: `in.readString` is used to read an entire line as a string of characters e.g. "0 2 100 1". You then call `split` to split this string (on tab) into an array of smaller strings {"0", "2", "100", "1"}. Finally, `Integer.parseInt` is used to convert strings to ints.